# Unit Test - method tests failed (labeltext.visible)

Tags: c#, unit-testing, methods, label, assert

I have the problem that my unit tests always fail but there is no point at all. I set the label.visible values to true and query they for true. How can that be? I write the values ​​in the console, they return false. But the method works in the program itself.

```
    // GETTER/SETTER
    internal void setlabeltest1Visible(bool xBool) { test1.Visible = xBool; }
    internal bool getlabelTest1Visible { get { return test1.Visible; } }
    internal void setlabeltest2Visible(bool xBool) { test2.Visible = xBool; }
    internal bool getlabelTest2Visible { get { return test2.Visible; } }


    // METHOD TO TEST
    internal void switchLabelVisibility(bool xFlag)
    {
        test1.Visible = xFlag;
        test2.Visible = xFlag;
    }


// UNIT TEST
   [TestMethod]
    public void switchLabelVisibility_Test()
    {
        //Arrange 
        var ExportTests = new Export();

        //Act //1. Fall - set visible values true
        ExportTests.switchLabelVisibility(true);

        //Assert
        Assert.IsTrue(
            ExportTests.getlabelTest1Visible &&
            ExportTests.getlabelTest2Visible
            ); // FAILS (values false)
```

Comment: Where are those labels on? A winforms Form? Is the form visible? If not, the label will be also invisible regardless of `Visible = true`.

Comment: Im not sure, its just a dummy object for tests. i will try this, thx.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. Now it Works correctly! Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx to @Steeeve, that works fine. :)

```
[TestMethod]
public void switchLabelVisibility_Test()
{
    //Arrange
    var ExportTests = new Export();
    ExportTests.Visible = true; // this works!

    //Act //1. Fall - Setze switchLabelVisibility true
    ExportTests.switchLabelVisibility(true);

    //Assert
    Assert.IsTrue(
    ExportTests.getlabelTest1Visible &&
    ExportTests.getlabelTest2Visible);
}
```